# How do I disable my @Html.ListBoxFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.listboxfor

I need to be able to disable this ListBoxFor() depending on the Review status. Although the code below works it shows all list items.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ListOptions, filetypes, Model.IsUnderReview ? new { @class = "disabled" } : new { @class = "multiselectFileTypes" })
```

What would be the syntax to disable it but just so it shows '2 items selected'?

Comment: Do note that disabling an HTML element does not prevent anyone from performing a POST request with its name. Also check this serverside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer is to use the Html.helper command HiddenFor(), like this

```
@if (Model.IsUnderReview)
{
    //You then need to generate a hidden input for each value in SelectedRoles, as it's an array
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedRoles) 
}
else
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedRoles, filetypes, new { @class = "multiselectFileTypes" , id = "staticFieldM_" + Model.ID})
}
```

By creating a hidden input for each SelectedRole item you then disable the whole list.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do inline condition checking for the `htmlAttributes` parameter.

This should work.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <label>Select something </label>
  if (!Model.IsUnderReview )
  {
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ListOptions, filetypes, new { @class = "multiselectFileTypes"})
  }
  else
  {
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ListOptions, filetypes, new { disabled = "disabled" })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it does work except for the fact that it displays the whole list of items. There must be something in the syntax that would fix this.

Comment: Disabled does not mean "Hide all items". It means show the items, but in a disable **"look"**

Comment: This is a terrible solution, but I can see why it is necessary. The `HtmlHelper` treats `name` differently in the `htmlAttributes` maybe it should treat `disabled` and `readonly` differently as well by accepting Boolean values and converting them to the idiotic `disabled="disabled"` nonsense. HTML's avoidance of Boolean values is the real culprit. I know why they did it that way, but today it is just dumb. I miss XAML. :.(